# Characterize all analytic functions satisfyinf the given condition

Tags: complex-analysis

> Characterize all analytic functions $f(z)$ in $|z|<1$ such that $|f(z)|\le |\sin(1/z)|$ , for all $0<|z|<1$.

I can't understand from where I will start ?

Comment: Say $w$ is a complex number and $|w|\le0$. What is $w$?

Comment: $w=0$....So what??

Comment: So think about what that might have to do with the problem...

Comment: How you can say that $\sin(1/z)=0$ ?

Comment: I don't understand the question...

Comment: Where is $\sin (1/x)=0$ on $(0,1)$?

Comment: So your analytic function equals $0$ at those points. Ring any bells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First prove that a non-constant analytic function can have at most finitely many zeros in a bounded, compact set. Proof idea: if it's bounded and compact, and has infinitely many zeros, there must be an accumulation point, so the function must be identically zero.

Now notice that $z_i=1/(n\pi)$ is such a sequence for $f(z)$.

Comment: So, $f(z)$ is identically zero...

Comment: How the domain $|z|<1$ is compact ? A compact set is always bounded. So in your statement **bounded and compact** is not necessary..Just compact is sufficient..

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: I never said $|z|<1$ is compact. You can show that $f(z)=0$ for $|z|\leq 1-\epsilon$ for any $1>\epsilon>0$ which will imply the result.